# Dell Latitude E6520 - Microphone is not detected

Tags: windows-10, drivers, microphone, dell-latitude

I have Dell Latitude E6520, with Windows 10 Pro 64 bits. When I try to record my voice, it says that there is no connected microphone. I couldn't find a driver for the microphone on Dell's website. The microphone is turned on in the Bios.

Any help, please?

Thank's

Comment: Microphone drivers are usually included with the audio drivers.  It's possible your laptop doesn't have a microphone. Could be disabled, go to Control Panel\Sound\Recording and select disabled/disconnected devices and see if the mic array is hidden there

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found this driver: https://www.dell.com/support/home/il/en/ilbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=t10v6

Now it works!